# < img src> as background image in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is it possible to make this my background

```
<img src="" alt="sample" width="480" height="500" border="0">
```

this is my code below i want to be able to make my images backgrounds and be able to change them the same way im doing it at the moment please help ive been asking and looking for an answer and all i get is how i can set on image as a background without being able to change it with a dropdown menu

```js
function fctCheck(gender) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByName("subselector");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
     elems.item(i).style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(gender).style.display = "block";
   }

$('#men').on('change', function () {
    $("#wsl").css('display', (this.value == 'lsm') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
$('#men').on('change', function () {
    $("#mtsm").css('display', (this.value == 'tsm') ? 'block' : 'none');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colore.active').each(function(){
   $('.container img').attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
  });
  $('.colore').on('click',function(){
   $('.container img').attr('src', '');
   $('.container img').attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
  });
});
```

```css
.container {background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;

}



.container2 {background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid;
    position: relative;
 
    overflow: auto;
}
.colore {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.white {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.yellow {
  background: #FAFF38;
}
.orange {
  background: #FFA200;
}

.red {
  background: #FF0000;
}
.dorange {
  background: #FF5500;
}
.lgreen {
  background: #80FF00;
}

.green {
  background: #45C731;
}

.turk {
  background: #17DDBC;
}
.lblue {
  background: #00A2FF;
}.blue {
  background: #1713F6;
}.purple {
  background: #AB09D3;
}.black {
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="container" style="float:left;">
 <img src="" alt="sample" width="150" height="150" border="0"></div>

<div  class="container2" style=" float: left;">
<select id="Gender" onchange="fctCheck(this.value);">
        <option value="">Choose Gender</option>
        <option value="men">Men</option>
        
    </select>  
    <br>
       <br>
    <select id="men" name="subselector" style="display:none">
      <option value="">Choose an item</option> 
      
      <option value="lsm">long sleeve</option>
     
     <
    </select>  
 
    
    <select id="wemen" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="slw">short sleeve</option>
 
    </select>  
    
     <select id="girls" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="shortsg">shorts</option>
        
    </select>  
 <select id="boys" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="tshirtb">tshirt</option>
       
    </select>  
     <div style='display:none;' id="wsl">
                       <div class="colore white active" data-image="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi.png">
                </div>
                <div class="colore black" data-image="http://mebe.co/ford">
                </div>
                <div class="colore yellow" data-image="http://mebe.co/f150">
                </div>
                <div class="colore orange" data-image="http://mebe.co/yukon">
                </div>
                <div class="colore red" data-image="http://mebe.co/370z">
                </div>
            </div>
            
          
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pureexample.com/js/lib/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script><script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Comment: I haven't read all of the source code but have your tried setting `z-index` for the image tag? Not really sure why you would want to use a image tag as the background image when you can simply use css `background:url();` but I'm sure you have your reasons.

Comment: no how would i do that

Comment: the reason is so that i can change my background using the drop down menu that i have created

Comment: You can change the css `background` property for an element all the same. You also have a typo **colore** It isn't causing any problems but just thought I would point that out.

Comment: i have to sets of code on is foo and the other i named it colore because on code called the other dont know why. can you point me the the right direction on how i can " change the css background property for an element" i appreciate your help

Comment: You seem to have jquery and jqueryui incude 2 or 3 times.  Once is plenty ;-)

Comment: thank you this is very helpful

Comment: how can i make this image bigger wide 500px height 500px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your sample code a bit and I think I have added the background switch you are looking for

```js
function fctCheck(gender) {
  $("select[name='subselector']").hide();
  $("#" + gender).show();
}

function setBackground(selector, url){
  $(selector).css("background-image", "url(" + url + ")" );
}

$("#men").on("change", function() {
  $("#wsl")[this.value === "lsm" ? "show" : "hide"]();
  $("#mtsm")[this.value === "tsm" ? "show" : "hide"]();
});

$(function() {
  setBackground("#box", $(".colore.active").attr("data-image"));

  $(".colore").on("click", function() {
    setBackground("#box", $(this).attr("data-image"));
  });
});
```

```css
#wsl { display:none; }
select[name='subselector'] { display:none; }
#box {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.container, .container2 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}

.colore {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.white { background: #FFFFFF; }
.yellow { background: #FAFF38; }
.orange { background: #FFA200; }
.red { background: #FF0000; }
.dorange { background: #FF5500; }
.lgreen { background: #80FF00; }
.green { background: #45C731; }
.turk { background: #17DDBC; }
.lblue { background: #00A2FF; }
.blue { background: #1713F6; }
.purple { background: #AB09D3; }
.black { background: #000000; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box" class="container"></div>

<div class="container2">
  <select id="Gender" onchange="fctCheck(this.value);">
    <option value="">Choose Gender</option>
    <option value="men">Men</option>
  </select>

  <select id="men" name="subselector">
    <option value="">Choose an item</option>
    <option value="lsm">long sleeve</option>
  </select>

  <div id="wsl">
    <div class="colore white active" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/200/200"></div>
    <div class="colore black" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"></div>
    <div class="colore yellow" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/160/160"></div>
    <div class="colore orange" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/170/170"></div>
    <div class="colore red" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/180/180"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image in background of the page then replace your `document.ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colore.active').each(function(){
    $('.container img').attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
  });
  $('.colore').on('click',function(){
    $('.container img').attr('src', '');
    $('.container img').attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
  });
});
```

With following `document.ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colore').on('click',function(){
     $('body').css('background-image','url(' +$(this).data("image")+')');
  });
});
```

Comment: This should be placed as a comment and not as a solution/answer. This can result in down votes. Just a heads up. It will take you longer to reach enough rep to be allowed to comment on posts if you use the answers form as a way to post comments.

Comment: how can i make this image bigger wide 500px height 500px

Comment: After this line

$('body').css('background-image','url(' +$(this).data("image")+')'); 

add following line

$('body').css('background-size', '500px 500px');

Answer (score 1):

Change HTML from this

```
<div id="box" class="container" style="float:left;">
 <img src="" alt="sample" width="150" height="150" border="0"></div>
```

To this

```
  <div id="box" class="container" style="float:left;"></div>
```

Change javascript from this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colore.active').each(function(){
    $('.container img').attr('src', $(this).data("image"));
```

To this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colore.active').each(function(){
     $('.container').css(
       'background-image','url(' +$(this).data("image")+')'
      );
```

Convert the rest of the $.attr calls to follow the $.css call example above.

Comment: it didnt work i am not able to change images i can only see one image im not able to change

Comment: how can i make this image bigger wide 500px height 500px

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the code was wrong this is the correct code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colore.active').each(function(){
     $('.container ').css(
       'background-image','url(' +$(this).data("image")+')'
      );
  });
  $('.colore').on('click',function(){
   $('.container').css('src', '');
   $('.container ').css('background-image','url(' +$(this).data("image")+')');
  });
});
```